# How to carry over Geometry Imports between scripts in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to access my Geometry Imports in all scripts within a repository in Google Earth Engine (for testing purposes, I want to make a copy of my main script that also has all of the Geometry Imports). By accident, I created a new script that happens to have my Geometry Imports from my main script, but I cannot figure out how that happened. Every time I try to create a new script with the Scripts Manager New drop-down button, it creates a new, empty script, but I cannot see the Geometry Imports from my main script in that repository.

How can I make a copy of a script (or a new one) that also has the Geometry Imports visible in another script in that same repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the script that has the Geometry Imports a module that you can import into other scripts by exporting the vars you need with `exports` and then in your script import them with `require`.

E,g, script named "imports" with the Geometry imports:

[image]

```
// code to export the variables 
exports.geometry1 = geometry1;
exports.geometry2 = geometry2;
```

Script named "script" that gets the geometry variables from "imports" and does something with them:

[image]

```
var imports = require('users/myusername/scripts:imports');
print(imports.geometry1);
print(imports.geometry2);
```

- scripts - the folder where imports file is located