# I would like to get a list of all the geometry I have created

Tags: google-earth-engine, geometry, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I would like to get a list of all the geometry I have created.

I can get individual geometry. For example "my_geometry2".

I tried follow link.
[How to carry over Geometry Imports between scripts in Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/422840/how-to-carry-over-geometry-imports-between-scripts-in-google-earth-engine)

However, I would like to get a list of all geometries in Imports.
It is impossible for the program to specify the names of the geometries, because the names of the geometries change dynamically.

How can I get a list of all geometries?

[image]

Comment: You can get to the geometry layers with Map.drawingTools().layers()

Comment: This question should be reopened because it is a question about working with geometry imports, which are not part of the code text. They can be _converted to_ text but the specific values are not relevant to the question which is about working them in their non-text form.